What can be done to combat the spam in discussions?
In recent weeks, I observed a steady stream of spam in discussions.
To name a few,

https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/79012049/how-can-i-get-a-refund-from-makemytrip
https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/79004716/psychic-27780802727-powerful-revenge-spells-bring-back-lost-lover-spells-cambod
https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/78988542/unprotect-sex971-588264028-cytotec-for-sale-in-dubai-abu-dhabi-sharjah-al
https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/78988467/exitvitalgmail-com-buy-nembutal-pentobarbital-sodium-online-buy-nembutal-pow
https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/78988422/sangoma-in-limpopo-2781-874-4558-%e0%af%b9in-polokwane-mankweng-seshego
https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/79032459/unlock-profitable-forex-trading-opportunities-in-india-a-gateway-to-financial-s
https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/79031855/the-digital-dawn
https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/79028481/unlocking-the-secrets-of-the-golden-neko-statue-in-bitlife-how-to-find-it-and-w
https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/79027299/would-you-like-a-stunning-beach-wedding-venue-or-formal-marriage-halls
https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/79042571/mastering-color-prediction-games-a-path-to-profitable-predictions
https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/79039389/haidilao-menu-canada
https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/79039127/how-to-migrate-protonmail-to-office-365
https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/79036434/voodoo-spell-casters-91-9878674982


A single account is allowed to post serial spam:

https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/79036513/temu-coupon-%e2%86%92-acq523678-100-off-first-order-free-shipping
https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/79042834/temu-coupon-code-100-off-acq794628-for-new-customer-new-york
https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/79041179/100-off-temu-coupon-code-acq523678-first-order
https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/79045008/temu-coupon-code-acq794628-first-order


Some may not be spam, but they look like blatantly non-sense:

https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/79012466/adgahsdgdghsdhasdhasdh
https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/79043924/how-many-times-can-someone-makes-payment-with-google-play-store-before-he-can-b

So,

Is discussions more vulnerable to spam than the main Q&A site?
If so, what could be the causes and what can we do to combat the spam in discussions?


It's not that discussions sees more spam, but that there is no API for it to be easily detected and removed. Spam on the main site can be removed pretty quickly, as it is easily detected by bots and can be automatically flagged. However, bots cannot detect posts on discussions, so the only way for them to be removed is by users manually flagging them.

So with regard to repeat spam, Discussions is more vulnerable as the penalties are not same as they would be on the main site. There is also the lack of quality bans which really help to slow down new posts. Also the visibility of discussions posts makes it more difficult to identify repeat spammers as there are minimal tools to search for discussions. Really, a lot of what I said the last time this came up is still true, though we have had several improvements and have also had a few more folks join in in the flag-handling efforts since then.

I reopened this because it is not really a duplicate of a post asking for changes to a system that saw those changes implemented well before this question was asked. The posts are related, but the answers to this question will be different, given the environment has changed.

I concur with @TylerH. This is a further ---cry for help--- asking for something to be implemented. That's after part of the previous things were done. It was clearly not enough.

Just close down Discussions already. I gave it a honest try but concluded that it is a doomed experiment, because pretty much every single thing with it is broken or low quality.

I found this thread when preparing to post on Meta – today I flagged around 6 Discussion posts in a couple of hours, which are either spam, unrelated to coding, and/or not in English. It's a waste of time visiting it, and it's getting worse. I've deleted my bookmark.

@WeatherVane For the past 1-2 weeks, my observation is that the trend is to use discussions as a "backdoor" to post low-quality questions that would be instantly closed if posted on the main site. Up to this moment, I am still unable to figure out the value of discussions.

@ray it was fine at first, but as the accepted answer – deem it a failed experiment. Nice try, though.

There's a number of options:

SE, Inc. could disable Discussions and deem it a failure, which would end spamming it :-)

As Fastnlight said, there isn't an API. I requested it here, but it's still status-deferred.

As Makyen◆ said in the context of handling an influx of spam, leaving spam for SE, Inc. staff members to deal with is an option. Deciding if that's an effective way to improve the spam issue is left as an exercise to the reader.

[...] While I'm strongly opposed to spam, I would have been quite tempted to just leave them there for the CMs to clean up. SE chose to implement something without the moderation capabilities that are minimally necessary in order to control the spam/R/A problem that was virtually guaranteed to exist [...] The community already goes a long way to clean up such things. I'm really frustrated that SE chose to make doing that cleanup harder, rather than putting enough in place for us to extend already existing processes.

Emphasis present in original comment. Quoted from Makyen◆ on MSO.

I'm not aware of more details, but Berthold (CM) said, "we're continuing to work on other spam-prevention approaches", so doing more of that might help.



"so doing more of that might help." maybe we can start with doing any of that. Because I don't think anything significant changed. It's possible that SE have done something about detecting a lot of traffic coming from one place or similar thing to combat big spam waves. But that's barely adequate in the face of Discussions getting spam every single day. It's not that much number-wise - several a day, but proportionally, it's still significant. I'd love to be able to get any stats on this but it feels like maybe 10-20% of discussions posted are spam.

@VLAZ Absolutely - for the number, I'd guess it's far higher than that, considering that at one point in time, there were over a thousand spam posts (for comparison, there's 875 discussions currently). I'm also not sure what "other [...] approaches" SE has in mind that will be more effective or less time-consuming to implement than enabling Charcoal to handle it. Do you think we'd get an answer if you or I posted a question about what other spam-prevention is being implemented?

I wouldn't expect to get an answer. But who knows.

An Increase [to the] reputation required to post a Discussion would also help, as all the spam comes from 1 rep accounts. Considering that most of the posts are from 1 rep users too, it'll really cut down on the posts, but 99% of those are bad posts so, net gain?

I am actually 100% in favour of just leaving it. What we see nowadays is features being implemented without proper guards in place against the fact that people suck. We got discussions without anti-spam measures, we got the staging ground where one vote can promote a post to the main site. That's going backwards, whatever knowledge should have been obtained from working on the site is not transferred to whomever is making the decisions today. So they need to relearn it, and it needs to hurt. You don't want spam? Well then put the relevant tickets on the backlog in a sprint for a change.

@ThomA But that's kinda the point of JunkOverflow Discussions, isn't it? I'm rather surprised people go there, let alone are bothered by it being a mess (did anyone expect anything else, other than perhaps SEI management?). What value is there for users like us in it -- just a half-assed reimplementation of the myriad of existing discussion forums on the web.

Honestly, I have yet to find a discussion that can truly provide meaningful insights and opinion exchange. I think this answer is not the one I hoped for, but the one that I have to accept as a (sad) fact.

Well, since I just learned discussions exist from this meta post, I'd vote for bullet 1, but it does seems like a pretty good idea to provide a separate space outside the strict QA to allow discussion. Moving comments to chat doesn't do that. Seems if the same SO account is required for discussion you should be able to impose the same penalties for spam violation (just delete the offending account). If it becomes a game of whack-a-mole, it may be more trouble than it's worth. In that case, bullet 1 again. It's kind of a sprawling reddit type thing.

@DavidC.Rankin "Well, since I just learned discussions exist from this meta post" my apologies. Hope your next week is better.

I"m checking it out, it's ... it's kinda free-form. Interesting. The interface is good.

A few months ago I outlined some easy fixes


Discussion flags need to show in their own area of the list of flags in the moderator list. This shouldn't be hard to add because (as I noted above) there's already a number to show
Red flags need to be red flags that carry an auto-deletion and SpamRam/rate limit penalties. Right now, they're just a text flag.
When a user is destroyed, their discussions are removed. The flags need to be removed (i.e. marked helpful) with them.
Charcoal can't even consider a fix here without an API feed of Discussions. I cannot speak for the Charcoal folks about if/when they would be able to scan Discussions, but I'd like to at least see this roadblock removed.


I'm pleased to say #2 and #3 are now fixed. #4 would be very useful, but is also the hardest to do. We still need #1 done. There's no way to see those flags unless you go to the Discussions page first (which we generally don't).
It would also be helpful if there was a breakdown of those flags by type. The flag handling list for them doesn't do that, so all flags are visibly red, spam or not.

#1 is only useful for SO mods. For the rest of us, it would also be useful to have a more convenient way to access Discussion flags, like the blue number on the top bar that diamond mods have.

For #2, may I ask for a case study on the serial spamming account mentioned in the question? Why that specific user is still allowed to serial spam? I understand that we may not want to disclose the internal mechanism of spam penalty so people can circumvent it. I just want to make sure #2 is functioning as intended and future spammers can be effectively stopped.

@ray FWIW, another mod has destroyed that user. If/when I see Discussion spam, I tend to remove the account as well. Not perfect, but it's the hand we've been dealt.

Many things can be done, but Stack Exchange Inc. won't do any of them because it would mean Line Does Not Go Up at the rate their executives want. So the correct answer is that nothing will be done and Discussions is working exactly as intended.

I was always told that StackOverflow is optimized for high-quality technical knowledge exchange where quantity should not matter... Seems like it is no longer the case and it will take some time for me to accept it...

@ray: Much of the community still curates and moderates the site that way.  The corporation that owns it doesn't understand (or seem to care much about) the community, so new site features and changes are usually either orthogonal to that goal or actively work against what the community wants.  Only a few of the employees actually use the site and understand how badly things suck.
